# Module with dynamic tags on Auto Scaling Group and EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to get dynamic tags on an [aws_autoscaling_group](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html) resource, but unlike the example in the documentation I do not yet now how many there will be.

So the following lines are set:

```
variable "tags" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    tag1 = "value1"
    tag2 = "value2"
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg" {
  name                 = "test-asg"
  launch_configuration = "test-lc"
  min_size             = 1
  max_size             = 1
  min_elb_capacity     = 1
  vpc_zone_identifier  = ["subnet-1234"]
  tags                 = <code_here>
}
```

I've come up with a solution that will support up to `x` dynamic tags. Unfortunately it uses dummy tags to fill up not provided tags up to `x`.

```
data "template_file" "test" {
  count    = "9"
  template = "key:@:$${key}:@:value:@:$${value}:@:propagate_at_launch:@:true"

  vars {
    key   = "${element(concat(keys(var.tags), list("unusedtag1", "unusedtag2","unusedtag3","unusedtag4","unusedtag5","unusedtag6","unusedtag7","unusedtag8","unusedtag9")), count.index)}"
    value = "${element(concat(values(var.tags), list("", "","","","","","","","")), count.index)}"
  }
}

locals{
  tag0 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.0.rendered)}"
  tag1 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.1.rendered)}"
  tag2 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.2.rendered)}"
  tag3 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.3.rendered)}"
  tag4 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.4.rendered)}"
  tag5 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.5.rendered)}"
  tag6 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.6.rendered)}"
  tag7 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.7.rendered)}"
  tag8 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.8.rendered)}"

  tags = "${list(
          map(local.tag0[0],local.tag0[1],local.tag0[2],local.tag0[3],local.tag0[4],local.tag0[5]),
          map(local.tag1[0],local.tag1[1],local.tag1[2],local.tag1[3],local.tag1[4],local.tag1[5]),
          map(local.tag2[0],local.tag2[1],local.tag2[2],local.tag2[3],local.tag2[4],local.tag2[5]),
          map(local.tag3[0],local.tag3[1],local.tag3[2],local.tag3[3],local.tag3[4],local.tag3[5]),
          map(local.tag4[0],local.tag4[1],local.tag4[2],local.tag4[3],local.tag4[4],local.tag4[5]),
          map(local.tag5[0],local.tag5[1],local.tag5[2],local.tag5[3],local.tag5[4],local.tag5[5]),
          map(local.tag6[0],local.tag6[1],local.tag6[2],local.tag6[3],local.tag6[4],local.tag6[5]),
          map(local.tag7[0],local.tag7[1],local.tag7[2],local.tag7[3],local.tag7[4],local.tag7[5]),
          map(local.tag8[0],local.tag8[1],local.tag8[2],local.tag8[3],local.tag8[4],local.tag8[5]),
          )}"
}
```

With this code in the ASG I can use `tags = ["${local.tags}"]`. With the example input the resources are tagged with

```
tag1 = value1
tag2 = value2
unusedtag1 = 
unusedtag2 = 
unusedtag3 = 
unusedtag4 = 
unusedtag5 =
unusedtag6 = 
unusedtag7 =
```

I would like to have a solution that is

- dynamic
- does tag extra tags

---

Edit: revert to unclear but simpler question and opened a new question on [terraform dynamic tags on ASG and other resources like EFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51207505/terraform-dynamic-tags-on-asg-and-other-resources-like-efs)

Comment: The example is dynamic, simply pass a list of dynamic tags and concatenate that with any statically defined tags.

Comment: thanks for the info, @ydaetskcoR. I might not have phrased the question in a good enough way. Please see the edit for the goal I would like to reach.

Comment: Then that's a completely different question to what you originally asked that was scoped to just the ASG. You should consider asking a new question that properly explains the outcome you want and what you have tried.

Comment: I've reverted the question, opened a new one and accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [example given in the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#interpolated-tags) shows the different ways you can add tags to an autoscaling group increasingly dynamically.

You can obviously just use the completely static `tag` stanzas like this:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "bar" {
  ...

  tag {
    key                 = "lorem"
    value               = "ipsum"
    propagate_at_launch = false
  }
}
```

Or you can use the more dynamic `tags` stanza that enables you to build a list of tags using `concat`:

```
variable extra_tags {
  default = [
    {
      key = "Foo"
      value = "Bar"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
    {
      key = "Baz"
      value = "Bam"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
  ]
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "bar" {
  ...

  tags = [
    {
      key                 = "explicit1"
      value               = "value1"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
    {
      key                 = "explicit2"
      value               = "value2"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
  ]

  tags = ["${concat(
    list(
      map("key", "interpolation1", "value", "value3", "propagate_at_launch", true),
      map("key", "interpolation2", "value", "value4", "propagate_at_launch", true)
    ),
    var.extra_tags)
  }"]
}
```

That second output, if the defaults weren't overridden would tag the ASG with:

```
explicit1 = value1
explicit2 = value2
interpolation1 = value3
interpolation2 = value4
Foo = Bar
Baz = Bam
```

If you were to override the `extra_tags` via tfvars such as:

```
extra_tags = [
  {
    key = "CustomTag1"
    value = "CustomValue1"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  },
  {
    key = "CustomTag2"
    value = "CustomValue3"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  },
  {
    key = "CustomTag3"
    value = "CustomValue3"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  },
  {
    key = "CustomTag4"
    value = "CustomValue4"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  },
]
```

Then your ASG would be tagged with:

```
explicit1 = value1
explicit2 = value2
interpolation1 = value3
interpolation2 = value4
CustomTag1 = CustomValue1
CustomTag2 = CustomValue2
CustomTag3 = CustomValue3
CustomTag4 = CustomValue4
```

This enables you to optionally have some tags that are always present on the ASG plus optional dynamic tags that are completely defined outside of your module or whatever.

Comment: please not that the input variable does not match the set input variable from my question.