# terraform dynamic tags on ASG and other resources like EFS

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to get dynamic tags on an [aws_autoscaling_group](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html) resource, but unlike the example in the documentation I do not yet now how many there will be and the tags **must be shared with other resources**. In the example below that would be EFS, but basically all other aws resources will be affected.

So the following lines are set:

```
variable "tags" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    tag1 = "value1"
    tag2 = "value2"
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg" {
  name                 = "test-asg"
  launch_configuration = "test-lc"
  min_size             = 1
  max_size             = 1
  min_elb_capacity     = 1
  vpc_zone_identifier  = ["subnet-1234"]
  tags                 = <code_here>
}

resource "aws_efs_file_system" "foo" {
  creation_token = "my-product"
  tags           = "${var.tags}"
}
```

I've come up with a solution that will support up to `x` dynamic tags. Unfortunately it uses dummy tags to fill up not provided tags up to `x`.

```
data "template_file" "test" {
  count    = "9"
  template = "key:@:$${key}:@:value:@:$${value}:@:propagate_at_launch:@:true"

  vars {
    key   = "${element(concat(keys(var.tags), list("unusedtag1", "unusedtag2","unusedtag3","unusedtag4","unusedtag5","unusedtag6","unusedtag7","unusedtag8","unusedtag9")), count.index)}"
    value = "${element(concat(values(var.tags), list("", "","","","","","","","")), count.index)}"
  }
}

locals{
  tag0 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.0.rendered)}"
  tag1 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.1.rendered)}"
  tag2 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.2.rendered)}"
  tag3 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.3.rendered)}"
  tag4 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.4.rendered)}"
  tag5 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.5.rendered)}"
  tag6 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.6.rendered)}"
  tag7 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.7.rendered)}"
  tag8 = "${split(":@:", data.template_file.test.8.rendered)}"

  tags = "${list(
          map(local.tag0[0],local.tag0[1],local.tag0[2],local.tag0[3],local.tag0[4],local.tag0[5]),
          map(local.tag1[0],local.tag1[1],local.tag1[2],local.tag1[3],local.tag1[4],local.tag1[5]),
          map(local.tag2[0],local.tag2[1],local.tag2[2],local.tag2[3],local.tag2[4],local.tag2[5]),
          map(local.tag3[0],local.tag3[1],local.tag3[2],local.tag3[3],local.tag3[4],local.tag3[5]),
          map(local.tag4[0],local.tag4[1],local.tag4[2],local.tag4[3],local.tag4[4],local.tag4[5]),
          map(local.tag5[0],local.tag5[1],local.tag5[2],local.tag5[3],local.tag5[4],local.tag5[5]),
          map(local.tag6[0],local.tag6[1],local.tag6[2],local.tag6[3],local.tag6[4],local.tag6[5]),
          map(local.tag7[0],local.tag7[1],local.tag7[2],local.tag7[3],local.tag7[4],local.tag7[5]),
          map(local.tag8[0],local.tag8[1],local.tag8[2],local.tag8[3],local.tag8[4],local.tag8[5]),
          )}"
}
```

With this code in the ASG I can use `tags = ["${local.tags}"]`. With the example input the resources are tagged with

```
tag1 = value1
tag2 = value2
unusedtag1 = 
unusedtag2 = 
unusedtag3 = 
unusedtag4 = 
unusedtag5 =
unusedtag6 = 
unusedtag7 =
```

I would like to have a solution that is

- dynamic
- does not use unnecessary tags
- **works with ASG and other AWS resources at the same time**
- simply propagates all tags on the ASG to the launched instances: `propagate_on_launch = true`

So the solution has to take the existing tags and add the `propagate_at_launch` key to it before adding it to the ASG.

Comment: Downvote and no comment isn't nice! Please explain why you down voted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now use Terraform's `dynamic "tag"` block to accomplish this. First, create a data resource:

```
data "aws_default_tags" "tags" {}
```

Next. insert this data resource into your target resource (like `aws_autoscaling_group`:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "foo" {
  desired_capacity          = 1
  force_delete              = true
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.foo.name
  max_size             = 4
  min_size             = 1
  name                 = var.resource_name
  placement_group      = aws_placement_group.foo.name
  vpc_zone_identifier  = [aws_subnet.private[*].id]

  dynamic "tag" {
    for_each = data.aws_default_tags.tags.tags
    content {
      key                 = tag.key
      value               = tag.value
      propagate_at_launch = true
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local map that holds the shared tags...

```
locals {
  shared_tags = "${map(
    "Foo", "1",
    "Bar", "2"
  )}"
}
```

...and then apply them (with optional merged updates) to tag attributes of resources:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg" {
  name                 = "test-asg"
  launch_configuration = "test-lc"
  min_size             = 1
  max_size             = 1
  min_elb_capacity     = 1
  vpc_zone_identifier  = ["subnet-1234"]
  tags                 = "${merge(local.shared_tags, map("Baz", "3"))}"
}

resource "aws_efs_file_system" "foo" {
  creation_token = "my-product"
  tags           = "${merge(local.shared_tags, map("Qux", "4"))}"
}
```

Props to [dwmkerr](https://github.com/dwmkerr) for the [idea](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2283) for this.

Comment: Hey @Eric. Thanks, but doesn't work. Because ASG needs a third parameter propagate_at_launch.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your question then. You do not have propogate_at_launch in your example. If you want instances launched by a tagged ASG to dynamically get updated tags, you cannot do that because the instances are not managed by Terraform. What do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: A dynamic tag would e.g. be the version of the deployment. Something that changes when you run terraform but not by itself afterwards. Basically all tags should be propagated to the instance.
Not having the propagate_at_launch in the original tags is exactly the problem. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That is an interesting problem, you should consider updating your question to make it clearer that this is the problem.

Comment: hmm. that was my try here. I already had a almost identical question that did get interpreted in a completely different way than expected. I've edited this question, did it make it more clear for you? If not feel free to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can then leverage the `aws_ec2_tag` resource, which works on non-ec2 resources as well, on conjunction with the provider attribute `ignore_tags`. Please refer to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64938829/2631728) I made on the topic for more detail.